# How to sort only a DatetimeIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, datetimeindex

I have a DatetimeIndex like this.

```
DatetimeIndex(['2015-04-29 00:00:00', '2016-02-22 16:00:00',
               '2016-02-12 04:00:00', '2016-02-16 04:00:00',
               '2016-02-09 12:00:00', '2016-02-11 07:00:00',
               '2015-08-06 00:00:00', '2014-10-31 00:00:00',
               '2014-11-14 00:00:00', '2015-09-24 00:00:00',
               ...
               '2015-12-30 00:00:00', '2015-11-30 00:00:00',
               '2016-02-19 20:00:00', '2014-11-13 00:00:00',
               '2014-12-15 00:00:00', '2015-06-16 00:00:00',
               '2015-12-31 00:00:00', '2015-01-09 00:00:00',
               '2015-11-25 00:00:00', '2015-03-12 00:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=604, freq=None)
```

and a (longer) Dataframe like this:

```
Df: 
                          Val       
Time                                                          
2014-10-10 00:00:00       ...  
2014-10-13 00:00:00       ...
2014-10-14 00:00:00       ...  
2014-10-15 00:00:00       ...
2014-10-16 00:00:00       ...  
                      ...       ...  ...            ...            ...
2016-02-23 16:00:00       ...
2016-02-23 17:00:00       ...   
2016-02-23 18:00:00       ... 
2016-02-23 19:00:00       ...   
2016-02-23 20:00:00       ...
```

How can I get the Dataframe with only the rows of it that are located on these indices ?

Comment: `Df.loc[your_date_list]`.

Answer (score 1):

If possible some values not matched use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) in[`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) :

```
df1 = df[df.index.isin(idx)]
```

Or [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) with select by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df1 = df.loc[df.index.intersection(idx)]
```

If all values matched is possible simplify answer with selecting only by `loc`, but it failed in new versions of pandas if at least one value not match:

```
df2 = df.loc[idx]
```